# Windows encoding with unicode?

Tags: r, windows, unicode

I have a package in development `cowsay` https://github.com/sckott/cowsay

I use unicode characters in some cases. E.g., https://github.com/sckott/cowsay/blob/master/R/animals.r#L167-L175

Those unicode characters are printed just fine in R on mac and linux machines, but on windows they do not print correctly.

Where on my mac `\uFF8A` gives

```
"\uFF8A"
[1] "ﾊ"
```

On the Windows machine I tried on I get

```
"\uFF8A"
[1] <U+FF8A>
```

The github issue is here https://github.com/sckott/cowsay/issues/9#issue-43149822

Since this is a package we hope can work across all major platforms, I'm hoping for a solution to this that just works without Windows users having to take an extra step that *unix users don't have to.

I think this has to do with encoding, but I'm not quite sure how to fix this, and I haven't found a solution googling/searching SO.

Comment: On windows, what does `Encoding()` return for those strings? Have you tried explicitly setting `Encoding()<-"UTF-8"` (assuming those are UTF-8)?

Comment: I wonder if `<U+FF8A>` is just an implementation’s way of saying that the font being used has no glyph for U+FF8A.

Comment: @MrFlick `Encoding()` on the string returned from a call to get one of those strings with unicode returns `UTF-8` on a windows machine. So this does work: `out <- say('hello', 'longcat', 'string'); Encoding(out) <- 'UTF-8'; out`. But, can this help somehow w/o users having to do this extra step on windows?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Interesting. What do you mean?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If the encoding is UTF-8, then the glyph should render properly. I copy/pasted "longcat" on a windows machine and it didn't show "\uFF8A" as in your example (running 3.1.1), it showed the glyph. I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: The meaning of `\uFF8A` does not depend on the character encoding of the program. There is no guarantee that the glyph renders properly; no font can contain all Unicode characters. What should rendering software do when it encounters a character without a glyph in the current font? It typically shows a generic “something went wrong” symbol or some box or other rendering containing the Unicode number of the character.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on my Windows machine.  `sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252`

Comment: @Andrie my R info is the same. The locale info is identical except for `English_United States.1252`. That is odd that you don't get the same problem. Any idea what could be causing me to have the problem? I'm on Windows 8 on virtualbox

Comment: The Windows console is broken and can't display the character you want. It looks like R is trying to be helpful by showing *something* where other languages commonly throw an exception. (Specifically: it's not actually the Windows console, but the MS C runtime. Apps using the C stdlib functions get byte IO based on the locale-specific code page, such as 1252, which can't represent all characters. In principle `chcp 65001` could be used to get something like UTF-8 but actually the MS CRT has long-standing bugs in this code page that tend to break everything.)